# Why do I receive 2 log files in log4js?

Tags: node.js, logging, log4js-node

I have the following configuration of my logger in a Node.js script:

```
const log4js = require('log4js');
 log4js.configure({
      appenders: {
        out: {
          type: "dateFile",
          filename: conf.logsFolder+"etl-processing.log",
          pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss",
          alwaysIncludePattern:true,
          keepFileExt:true
        }
      },
      categories: {
         default: { appenders: ['out'], level: 'debug' }
      }
    });
    const logger = log4js.getLogger();
    logger.info ("yada yada yada...")
    logger.error ("yada yada yada...")
```

Why does log4js produce two log files: one empty and one with all logs? Am I missing something?
The result is always sth like this (2 files separated in time with 1 sec):

1. etl-processing.2022-10-04-13-40-29.log
2. etl-processing.2022-10-04-13-40-30.log

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, you will get a new logfile every second (as long as there's something to be logged) because you're including `-ss` in the pattern (the pattern is used to determine the _current_ filename it should log to, not just the filename of the first logfile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pattern` argument refers to the date pattern added to the file **name**. With the configuration you provided, it will roll over every second. You could change the `pattern` to something a bit more lax, or even omit it entirely and let it default to `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: You are totally right!  Thank you!